# Reversing the order of items within a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to reverse the order of items stored within a list box that is populated via Sql-Server? I am using ASP.NET and C# and the methods I have found do not seem to contain the .Reverse() extension.  Is there another way to do it?

Here is my code (lbProjects is the ListBox)

ListBox - C#

```
 String Sql = @" select * from project";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Properties.Resources.cString);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            DA.Fill(DS, "Project");
            DataTable DT = DS.Tables["Project"];

            lbProjects.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
            lbProjects.DataTextField = "ProjectName";
            lbProjects.DataSource = DT;
            lbProjects.DataBind();
```

ListBox - ASP.NET

```html
<asp:ListBox runat="server" 
    ID="lbProjects" 
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbProjects_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    Width =" 350px">
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: It's pretty bad practice to use inline SQL, though. I would consider putting this into a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017), if I were you, and using [parameters](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/) where necessary.

Comment: Yeah I agree but this list box I am using is temporary, going to change it to a search bar after a couple weeks.  Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `OrderBy descending` or `ascending` in your query.

So basically, change your query to:

```
@"select * from project order by ProjectId desc"
```

And replace `ProjectId` with whatever field you want to sort the query by.

Comment: never thought of using the sql query.  Can't believe that passed my head like that, thanks!.  Ill accept the answer after the time delay is up

Comment: Sometimes the obvious answer just passes by because you're too focused on your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.  The easiest would be to change your query:

```
String Sql = @" select * from project order by ProjectID desc";
```

Or `ProjectName desc` - whichever you desire.